# multiple xml files from directory to character strings in R

Tags: r, xml, loops, for-loop, import

I have seen several similar questions, but none that addressed specifically my problem:

given a novel in xml file (this is a very small cut from the start and the end)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="https://github.com/COST-ELTEC/Schemas/raw/master/eltec-0.rng" type="application/xml"schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="https://github.com/COST-ELTEC/Schemas/raw/master/eltec-0.rng" type="application/xml"schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="CHE-DEU011" xml:lang="de">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>Pilatus. Eine Erzählung aus den Bergen: ELTeC ausgabe</title>
                <author ref="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Federer">Federer, Heinrich (1866-1928)</author>
                <respStmt>
                    <resp>ELTeC conversion</resp>
                    <name>Priska Rüegg</name>
                </respStmt>
            </titleStmt>
            <extent>
                <measure unit="pages">360</measure>
                <measure unit="words">79740</measure>
            </extent>
            
            <publicationStmt>
                <publisher ref="https://distant-reading.net">COST Action "Distant Reading for European Literary History" (CA16204)
                </publisher>
                <distributor ref="https://zenodo.org/communities/eltec/">Zenodo.org</distributor>
                <date when="2020"/>
                <availability>
                    <licence target="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/"/>
                </availability>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <bibl type="digitalSource">
                    <ref target="https://archive.org/details/pilatuseineerz00fedeuoft/page/n3/mode/2up"/>
                    <respStmt><resp>Scan</resp>
                        <name>archive</name></respStmt></bibl>
                <bibl type="firstEdition">
                    <title>Pilatus. Eine Erzählung aus den Bergen</title>
                    <author>Federer, Heinrich</author>
                    <publisher>G. Grote`sche Verlagsbuchhandlung</publisher>
                    <pubPlace>Berlin</pubPlace>
                    <date>1912</date>
                </bibl></sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
        <encodingDesc n="eltec-0">
            <p></p>
        </encodingDesc>
        <profileDesc>
            <langUsage>
                <language ident="de">German</language>
            </langUsage>
            <textDesc>
                <authorGender xmlns="http://distantreading.net/eltec/ns" key="M"></authorGender>
                <size xmlns="http://distantreading.net/eltec/ns" key="medium"></size>
                <reprintCount xmlns="http://distantreading.net/eltec/ns" key="low"></reprintCount>
                <timeSlot xmlns="http://distantreading.net/eltec/ns" key="T4"></timeSlot>
            </textDesc>
        </profileDesc>
        <revisionDesc>
            <change when="2020-10-27"> I created the document. The Scan is used only to check page beginnings, paragraphs, chapters and heads.</change>
            <change when="2020-11-08">I revised the document. I put "–" instead of "+"; I put "!" instead of "]". I checked the headers. In the original the chapter number 23 appears twice. I encoded a header appearing on two lines as two succesive headers as element p is not allowed.</change>
        </revisionDesc>
    </teiHeader>
    <text>
<body>  
<pb n="1"/>
<div type="liminal">
<p>Ich will hier die Geschichte des Marx Omlis erzählen.
Er ist frühauf ein Schlingel und daneben Hirt
und Jäger und Bergführer und sonst noch viel Unruhiges gewesen. In seinem Leben gibt es leichte und
schwere Kapitel und mit so bunten Gesichtern, daß man
zweifeln könnte, ob es immer der nämliche Held sei.
Aber immer schauen die gleichen Berge herein mit
langen, grauen Felsenleibern und Silberhüten auf dem
Kopf. Und immer leuchten die gleichen grünen Alpen
aus ihrem Schoß herauf und schellt und brüllt es vom
gleichen braunscheckigen Vieh um all die niedrigen Stadel
und ihre alten, steinbeschwerten Schindeldächer. Vor
allem aber dräut aus jedem Blatt immer der gleiche
wilde und schöne Kopf des Pilatus gen Himmel. Und
am Pilatus klebt und hängt das Leben des Marx Omlis
fest. Von ihm hat er sich nicht losmachen können, so
weit er auch floh. Der graue, alte Berg spielt die
Hauptrolle in seinem Leben. Er war sein Freund und
Feind, ist seine Wiege und sein Grabstein geworden.
~ Ich will mich sammeln und alles sachte und gelassen meinen lieben, besinnlichen Lesern auskramen.</p></div>
<div type="chapter">
<head>I.</head>
<p>Unser Gebirgsstädtchen hat ein Gymnasium mit
sehr weisen Lehrern, sehr tiefen Tintengeschirren und
sehr langen Sommerferien. Aber das beste von allem
sind doch die breiten, großscheibigen Fensterreihen rundum am Haus gewesen. Da drang ein unsäglich reiner,
am Horn in der andern Hand, alles hübsch nebeneinander gebettet, Mensch und Tier und Fels und
Schnee. Und weil diese Buben noch so frisch und jung
sind und darum vor dem Tod noch einen heiligen Respekt haben, so ziehen sie vor dem schönen, langen, stillen
Mann und seinem zierlichen Tier ihre Filzhüte ab und
sagen fromm: „Herr, gib ihnen die ewige Ruhe !“</p></div>
</body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

of which I am only interested in the "text" (body of the book), I managed to extract it from a single file with the following code:

```
library(XML)
library(tidyverse)

test <- "files/Federer1912_Pilatus.xml"

xmldoc <- xmlParse(test)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(xmldoc)
# rootNode[1]
data <- xmlSApply(rootNode,function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
cd.catalog <- data.frame(t(data),row.names=NULL)
federer_1912_pilatus <- cd.catalog$text
federer_1912_pilatus <- federer_1912_pilatus[["text"]]
```

Is there a way to loop this operation for each of the many xml files in a specific folder, called "files"?

And eventually would it be possible to put all the extracted strings directly in a data.frame with two variables: one for the "book_name" - in which for example "federer_1912_pilatus" will appear for the text above - and one for the "text" itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. Put your code in a function which takes a filename as an argument
2. Use `list.files` to get a vector of all xml files in your directory
3. Use e.g. `lapply` to loop over the files, which will return a list of your texts.

```
    get_text <- function(fn) {     
      xmldoc <- xmlParse(fn)
      rootNode <- xmlRoot(xmldoc)
      # rootNode[1]
      data <- xmlSApply(rootNode,function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
      cd.catalog <- data.frame(t(data),row.names=NULL)
      x <- cd.catalog$text
      x[["text"]]
    }
    
    xml_files <- list.files(path = "files", pattern = "\\.xml", full.names = TRUE)
    
    lapply(xml_files, get_text)
```

**EDIT** Instead of looping via `lapply` you could make use of `purrr::safely` and `purrr::map`. This does not solve the issue with the corrupted xml files but takes care of the error. The following code will return a list `res` with the results for non-corrupted files and a list of the corrupted files:

```
get_text_safe <- purrr::safely(get_text)

texts <- purrr::map(xml_files, get_text_safe)
texts <- purrr::transpose(texts)

# Error
id_error <- map_lgl(texts$result, ~ is.null(.x)) 

# Results for files which are fine
res <- texts$result[!id_error]

fn_error <- xml_files[id_error]
fn_error
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer: i tried but it gives me an Error and I am not sure what that is about: ```Error: 1: EndTag: '</' not found```

Comment: Hm. Looks like that at least one of your xml files is corrupted, i.e. there is a missing "</". I just made an edit. This does not solve the issue but takes care of any errors. Unfortunately I have no solution for how to proceed with the corrupted files. The first thing I would do is to have a look at one of the files (hopefully it's only one ...) and to try to check out what's the issue. Maybe you could fix this manually ...

Comment: yes i think there are mistakes in the xml files unfortunately. thanks anyway!